# Android BindingConversion multiple parameters

Tags: android, binding, data-conversion

I've wrote this BindingConversion:

```
@BindingConversion
public static String convertDateToFormat(Date date, String format) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
}
```

And in my layout file:

```
<TextView
 android:text="@{BindingUtils.convertDateToFormat(schedule.dateStart, `EEEE`)}"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
```

But it fails to build.

Can someone explain me how I can pass multiple parameters to and binding conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android [documation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingConversion.html)

> The converter should take one parameter, the expression type, and the return value should be the target value type used in the setter

Having parameters isn't currently supported.

You could instead use a BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({ "date", "format" })
public static void bindDate(final TextView view, final ZonedDateTime date, final String format) {
    if (date != null) {
        view.setText(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).format(date));
    }
}
```